# How can IE11 upload file which is no longer exists

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload

I have a file upload form.
After selected upload file, I delete the selected file (or rename it) by window explorer, then submit form.

With Chrome, Firefox and IE8, the server is received a blank file (filesize = 0). But with IE11, the file is uploaded successfully.

I can't understand why IE11 can upload a file which is no longer exists?

---

I wrote a script check input file here: http://jsfiddle.net/Teddy_Heaven/U5tjR/8/

```
[html]
<input type="file" id="test" />
<input type="button" onclick="checkFile()" value="Submit" />

[script]
function checkFile() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    try {
    if(typeof el.files[0] !== 'undefined' && el.files[0].size > 0)
        alert("Success!");
    else
        alert("No file found!");
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name == "NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND") {
            alert("file no longer exists");
        }
    }
};
```

Just select a file, rename file, then click submit.
With chrome: No file found!
With Firefox: file no longer exists
With IE11: Success!

Comment: Shouldn't you be logging this as a bug with IE and not posting this on SO? Seems like an extreme edge case. :)

Comment: I wonder if IE use cache or something like that for upload file, because it can get data of a no-longer-exists file

Answer (score 0):

I have a same question, when I saw your question, I get a idea. We can use other way to get the result，such as：

```
[script]
    function checkFile() {
        var el = document.getElementById("test");
        try {
        if(typeof el.files[0] !== 'undefined' && el.files[0].size > 0)
            alert("Success!");
        else
            alert("No file found!");
        } catch (err) {
                alert("No file found!");//in IE11, if file not exists, it will catch a error!
            }
        }
    };
```

I come from chinese and have a poor English, I hope you could understand my answer, wish the answer helpful to you^_^